# Blowfish Crypt confusion

Tags: php

Not sure why but i think i have totally not understood how this works....

I found an example script which had this:

```
echo crypt('abc123', '$2a$04$saltsaltsaltsaltsaltxx');
```

And it claims to give the output:

```
$2a$04$saltsaltsaltsaltsaltxuK2.MS4sJd6ZjnuS0fp2eenjndo.g4hS
```

But when i did it the same code i get:

```
 $2pGiQ0v1IyNY
```

As an output... doesn't really explain anything to me so far or why i get a different output to the example i saW?

I'm trying to get the sale + the hashed password and store them in the user table for each user but I'm not following how to:

a) generate a random salt per user

b) get the salt and the hash password from it to store it ?

c) how you then check it on for example a login page

Comment: What is your PHP version? I copy+pasted your sample code in 5.3.10 and got exactly what you are expecting, not what you're getting.

Comment: @lanzz PHP Version 5.2.5 according to phpinfo();

Comment: I see in the docs: `As of PHP 5.3.0, PHP contains its own implementation and will use that if the system lacks of support for one or more of the algorithms.` It could be that you don't have some libraries that pre-5.3.0 PHP required for Blowfish support, or it was specifically compiled without Blowfish support.

Comment: @lanzz So should i just upgrade to 5.3?

Comment: It might be easier than trying to figure why your installation has no blowfish support.

Comment: Okay ill ask my host to sort it out - and let you know if that fixes the problem :)

Comment: @lanzz ok i got this now "$2a$04$saltsaltsaltsaltsaltxuK2.MS4sJd6ZjnuS0fp2eenjndo.g4hS"  how do i know what is the salt and what is the hashed password ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From PHP docs:

> Blowfish hashing with a salt as follows: "$2a$", a two digit cost parameter, "$", and 22 digits from the alphabet "./0-9A-Za-z". Using characters outside of this range in the salt will cause crypt() to return a zero-length string. The two digit cost parameter is the base-2 logarithm of the iteration count for the underlying Blowfish-based hashing algorithmeter and must be in range 04-31, values outside this range will cause crypt() to fail.

You don't need to split the salt from the hashed password. You store the entire string ("$2a$04$saltsaltsaltsaltsaltxuK2.MS4sJd6ZjnuS0fp2eenjndo.g4hS"), and when you want to verify if a provided password matches your hash, you do

```
if (crypt($form_password, $stored_hash) == $stored_hash) {
    // password is correct
}
```